# Where can I get a custom helmet?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Where can I get hold of the custom helmets seen on some of the other players?

During an online race I see other players with custom helmets ... where can I get one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clothing store -> Hats -> Helmets.